# How can I test this stored function in OracleDB with JMeter JDBC Request?

Tags: java, jmeter, callable-statement

I am trying to make a performance test for stored procedures and functions in OracleDB, but I get this error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

The connection works just fine, I already tried to do some queries, but I don't know what to do with callable statements.

My JDBC Request looks like this:

```
call DB_SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME(?,?)

Parameter values: COD,USERNAME
Parameter types: VARCHAR,VARCHAR
```

Sorry, I can't post any image at the moment.

This is the function called with oracle.

```sql
declare
    result VARCHAR2(4000);
    P_CODCOMPANY VARCHAR2(4000) := 'COD';
    P_USERNAME VARCHAR2(4000) := 'USERNAME';
begin
    result := DB_SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME.FUNCTION_NAME(
        P_CODCOMPANY => P_CODCOMPANY,
        P_USERNAME => P_USERNAME
    );
    open ? for select result as result from dual;
end;
```

Comment: Are you connecting to database as `DB_SCHEMA` user? If not have you checked that your user actually has grants to execute `DB_SCHEMA.PACKAGE_NAME` package?

Comment: Yes, I am connecting with DB_SCHEMA user